# Kendo combobox not retaining value after page refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using ASP.NET MVC. I have a form and in it I have the following code for selecting a gender:

```
          Kendo()
                  .ComboBox()
                  .Name("OG1Geslacht")
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:250px" })
                  .Placeholder("Selecteer geslacht...")
                  .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>()
                  {
                      new SelectListItem()
                      {
                        Text = "Man", Value = "0"
                      },
                      new SelectListItem()
                      {
                        Text = "Vrouw", Value = "1"
                      },
                      new SelectListItem()
                      {
                          Text = "Onbekend", Value = "2"
                      }
                  })
            )
```

When the user submits the form, but there's a validation error somewhere, the page refreshes. The selected gender value is still there. I also have a validation check on this control.

What happens is that the next time the user wants to submit the form, there's a validation error on this control. The user has to change his selected value and then back again for it to be "noticed" again to come along with the form post. This is not very user friendly of course, and so I would like to know how to solve this problem.

Thanks!

-- EDIT --
The validation that is on `OG1Geslacht`:

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Het veld 'Geslacht' van objectgebruiker 1 is verplicht!")]
        [Display(Name = "Geslacht")]
        public string OG1Geslacht { get; set; }
```

Comment: What is the error? Are you able you reproduce it using [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/uSaVU)?

Comment: Does you model contain a property named `OG1Geslacht` and what validation attributes are applied to it?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added to my post the code for the validation. In short:yes, there is validation, a `required` data annotation on the property of the viewmodel.

Comment: @Sandman Looking at Dojo right now and trying if I can get something working.

Comment: Its not clear what your claiming. All your options are valid so there cannot be a validation error unless there is other code your not showing us (and why is the property `string` when the values are `int`?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I can't tell you why they are strings instead of ints. Not because I don't want to mind you, but because I don't know. The thing I'm claiming: A user fills in the form, and selects a gender. This field is required, but they select a gender, no problems. Let's say there's a validation error on any other field. So the page refreshes and shows the validation errors. The fields are still filled in, this applies to gender as well. But then when the user tries to submit the form, it gives a validation error for the gender dropdown, even though the selected value is still there!

Comment: The Kendo ComboBox method generates it own html and makes a hidden input for the property your binding to. By default hidden inputs are not even validated. How are you generating the placeholder for the validation message?

Comment: Also is there a reason your using ComboBox (which allows the user to enter an alternative text value) instead of DropDownList

Comment: I think what happens is that it is only visual. I.e., you see your selected gender, but nothing gets send to the server. On the server, it sees that there's a null value for gender, and since it is required it adds the error to the model state. There's no reason to use ComboBox. Users shouldn't be able to fill anything in for gender!